# Apache test page, instead of Django app showing up after server is started

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat, virtualhost, python, django

I have an app on EC2 that I start up by ssh'ing into the VM, activating the `env` and then running `manage.py runserver`. The Django app starts without any errors on `127.0.0.1:8000`. 
The server files within `/etc/httpd` were migrated from an `Apache 2.2` setup, using instructions from the official Redhat migration instructions.

From within the VM, I send a request to the same address using `wget http://127.0.0.1:8000`. The response was:

```
--2018-08-06 15:30:16--  http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

Next, I took a `tcpdump` using very verbose and zero snapshots and all it produced `Got 0` responses.

When I navigate to the ip address either on the `https` or `http` it only shows me the Redhat Enterprise Linux Test Page.

The apache configuration file is copied below. I have configured my VHOSTS in a separate file. Could this all be due a permissions issue? Do I need to provide some sort of permissions on the `/etc/httpd` and `/var/www/app` folders as defined in the configuration file?

```
ServerTokens OS

ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"


PidFile run/httpd.pid

Timeout 60

KeepAlive Off

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 5

Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxRequestWorkers       256
MaxConnectionsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>

<IfModule worker.c>
StartServers         4
MaxRequestWorkers         300
MinSpareThreads     25
MaxSpareThreads     75 
ThreadsPerChild     25
MaxConnectionsPerChild  0
</IfModule>


Listen 80

LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
#LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
#LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
#LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
LoadModule suexec_module modules/mod_suexec.so
#LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so

#
# The following modules are not loaded by default:

LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
#
Include conf.d/*.conf


#
User apache
Group apache

#
ServerAdmin root@localhost


UseCanonicalName Off


DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>


<Directory "/var/www/html">


    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride None

    Require all granted

</Directory>


<IfModule mod_userdir.c>

    UserDir disabled


</IfModule>

#
#
DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var

AccessFileName .htaccess


<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    #Order allow,deny
    #Deny from all
    Require all denied
    #Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>


TypesConfig /etc/mime.types


#
DefaultType text/plain


<IfModule mod_mime_magic.c>
#   MIMEMagicFile /usr/share/magic.mime
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>


#
HostnameLookups Off


#EnableMMAP off

#EnableSendfile off


ErrorLog logs/error_log


#
LogLevel warn


#
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

#
CustomLog logs/access_log combined


ServerSignature On


#
Alias /icons/ "/usr/share/httpd/icons/"

<Directory "/usr/share/httpd/icons">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    #Order allow,deny
    #Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#
# WebDAV module configuration section.
# 
<IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
    # Location of the WebDAV lock database.
    DAVLockDB /var/lib/dav/lockdb
</IfModule>


#
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"


#
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    #Order allow,deny
    #Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>


IndexOptions FancyIndexing VersionSort NameWidth=* HTMLTable Charset=UTF-8


#
AddIconByEncoding (CMP,/icons/compressed.gif) x-compress x-gzip

AddIconByType (TXT,/icons/text.gif) text/*
AddIconByType (IMG,/icons/image2.gif) image/*
AddIconByType (SND,/icons/sound2.gif) audio/*
AddIconByType (VID,/icons/movie.gif) video/*

AddIcon /icons/binary.gif .bin .exe
AddIcon /icons/binhex.gif .hqx
AddIcon /icons/tar.gif .tar
AddIcon /icons/world2.gif .wrl .wrl.gz .vrml .vrm .iv
AddIcon /icons/compressed.gif .Z .z .tgz .gz .zip
AddIcon /icons/a.gif .ps .ai .eps
AddIcon /icons/layout.gif .html .shtml .htm .pdf
AddIcon /icons/text.gif .txt
AddIcon /icons/c.gif .c
AddIcon /icons/p.gif .pl .py
AddIcon /icons/f.gif .for
AddIcon /icons/dvi.gif .dvi
AddIcon /icons/uuencoded.gif .uu
AddIcon /icons/script.gif .conf .sh .shar .csh .ksh .tcl
AddIcon /icons/tex.gif .tex
AddIcon /icons/bomb.gif core

AddIcon /icons/back.gif ..
AddIcon /icons/hand.right.gif README
AddIcon /icons/folder.gif ^^DIRECTORY^^
AddIcon /icons/blank.gif ^^BLANKICON^^

#
DefaultIcon /icons/unknown.gif


# directory indexes. 
ReadmeName README.html
HeaderName HEADER.html


#
IndexIgnore .??* *~ *# HEADER* README* RCS CVS *,v *,t



AddLanguage ca .ca
AddLanguage cs .cz .cs
AddLanguage da .dk
AddLanguage de .de
AddLanguage el .el
AddLanguage en .en
AddLanguage eo .eo
AddLanguage es .es
AddLanguage et .et
AddLanguage fr .fr
AddLanguage he .he
AddLanguage hr .hr
AddLanguage it .it
AddLanguage ja .ja
AddLanguage ko .ko
AddLanguage ltz .ltz
AddLanguage nl .nl
AddLanguage nn .nn
AddLanguage no .no
AddLanguage pl .po
AddLanguage pt .pt
AddLanguage pt-BR .pt-br
AddLanguage ru .ru
AddLanguage sv .sv
AddLanguage zh-CN .zh-cn
AddLanguage zh-TW .zh-tw

LanguagePriority en ca cs da de el eo es et fr he hr it ja ko ltz nl nn no pl pt pt-BR ru sv zh-CN zh-TW


#
ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
#
AddType application/x-compress .Z
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
#
AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl

#
AddHandler type-map var

#
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml

Alias /error/ "/usr/share/httpd/error/"

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
<IfModule mod_include.c>
    <Directory "/usr/share/httpd/error">
        AllowOverride None
        Options IncludesNoExec
        AddOutputFilter Includes html
        AddHandler type-map var
        #Order allow,deny
        #Allow from all
        Require all granted
        LanguagePriority en es de fr
        ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
    </Directory>


</IfModule>
</IfModule>

BrowserMatch "Mozilla/2" nokeepalive
BrowserMatch "MSIE 4\.0b2;" nokeepalive downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "RealPlayer 4\.0" force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "Java/1\.0" force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "JDK/1\.0" force-response-1.0

#
BrowserMatch "Microsoft Data Access Internet Publishing Provider" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "MS FrontPage" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^WebDrive" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^WebDAVFS/1.[0123]" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^gnome-vfs/1.0" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^XML Spy" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^Dreamweaver-WebDAV-SCM1" redirect-carefully


#<Location /server-status>
#    SetHandler server-status
#    Order deny,allow
#    Deny from all
#    Allow from .example.com
#</Location>


#<Location /server-info>
#    SetHandler server-info
#    Order deny,allow
#    Deny from all
#    Allow from .example.com
#</Location>


#<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
#ProxyRequests On
#
#<Proxy *>
#    Order deny,allow
#    Deny from all
#    Allow from .example.com
#</Proxy>


#ProxyVia On


#<IfModule mod_disk_cache.c>
#   CacheEnable disk /
#   CacheRoot "/var/cache/mod_proxy"
#</IfModule>
#

#</IfModule>
# End of proxy directives.

### Section 3: Virtual Hosts
#
# VirtualHost: If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
#NameVirtualHost *:80
#
# NOTE: NameVirtualHost cannot be used without a port specifier 
# (e.g. :80) if mod_ssl is being used, due to the nature of the
# SSL protocol.
#

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for requests without a known
# server name.
#
#<VirtualHost *:80>
#    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
#    DocumentRoot /www/docs/dummy-host.example.com
#    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
#    ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
#    CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
#</VirtualHost>
```

Below is a masked version of the virtual hosts configuration file.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin pmy@my-organization.com
    ServerName app-domain.my-organization.com
    Redirect permanent / https://app-domain.my-organization.com/
    </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin pmy@my-organization.com
    ServerName differentapp-domain.my-organization.com
    Redirect permanent / https://differentapp-domain.my-organization.com/
    </VirtualHost>


WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi

WSGIDaemonProcess staging_app_py python-path=/var/www/staging_app:/var/www/staging_app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIDaemonProcess app_py python-path=/var/www/app:/var/www/app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIDaemonProcess staging_app_py2 python-path=/var/www/staging_app2:/var/www/staging_app2/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages

WSGIDaemonProcess app_py2 python-path=/var/www/app2:/var/www/app2/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin pmy@my-organization.com
    ServerName app-domain.my-organization.com
    SSLEngine On

    Alias /staging/static/ /var/www/staging_app/public/static/
    <Directory /var/www/staging_app/public/static>
        #Order allow,deny
        #Allow from all
        Require all granted
        </Directory>
    WSGIScriptAlias /staging /var/www/staging_app/app/wsgi.py
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    <Directory /var/www/staging_app/app>
        #Order allow,deny
        #Allow from all
        Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /archive/static/ /var/www/staging_app2/public/static/
    <Directory /var/www/staging_app2/public/static>
        #Order allow,deny
        #Allow from all
        Require all granted
        </Directory>
    WSGIScriptAlias /archive /var/www/staging_app2/app/wsgi.py
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    <Directory /var/www/staging_app2/app>
        #Order allow,deny
        #Allow from all
        Require all granted
        </Directory>

    Alias /static/ /var/www/app/public/static/
    <Directory /var/www/app/public/static>
        #Order allow,deny
        #Allow from all
        Require all granted
        </Directory>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/app/app/wsgi.py
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    <Directory /var/www/app/app>
        #Order allow,deny
        #Allow from all
        Require all granted
        </Directory>

    <Location />
        WSGIProcessGroup app_py
        </Location>
    <Location /staging>
        WSGIProcessGroup staging_app_py
        </Location>
        <Location /archive>
        WSGIProcessGroup staging_app_py2
        </Location>

    </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin pmy@my-organization.com
    ServerName differentapp-domain.my-organization.com
    SSLEngine On

    Alias /static/ /var/www/app2/public/static/
    <Directory /var/www/app2/public/static>
        #Order allow,deny
        #Allow from all
        Require all granted
        </Directory>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/app2/app/wsgi.py
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    <Directory /var/www/app2/app>
        #Order allow,deny
        #Allow from all
        Require all granted
        </Directory>

    <Location />
        WSGIProcessGroup app_py2
        </Location>

    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Did you read the text on the test page?  It's instructions for turning it off.

Comment: If you run your app in mod_wsgi, you do not need to, and should not, run another copy with manage.py runserver. In this configuration, Apache mod_wsgi starts your app.

Comment: @yoonix, the test page text just says that as a web admin, I may add stuff to `/var/www/`, which I already have done

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I followed the following [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04), that said we have to use run server. Could you please provide a link to the proper way

Comment: The tutorial is correct. As it said, you are meant to _test_ your app by running it that way, but you do not do that anymore once you run it in Apache mod_wsgi.

Comment: @MichaelHampton true, the Django server runs fine without problems as I mentioned, but I don't see anything when I navigate to the web root.